# JText string in helper.php

Tags: php, joomla, localizable.strings

I want to return a JText value from my helper.php file from my own module.

```
class modMyFormularHelper
{ 
  public static function getValue()
  {
    $test =  JText::_('MOD_MYFORMULAR_VALUE');
    return $test;
  }
```

For this I have a "de-DE.mod_myformular.ini" in the language folder. The problem is I only get MOD_MYFORMULAR_VALUE in the Frontend.

If I write the JText in the default.php from the tmpl-folder... This works fine!

So how can I get the language strings in the helper file? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.  The first you already know, which is to migrate the JText::_(); method to the default.php file.  The second is to manually load the language file inside the getValue() method like so:

```
JFactory::getLanguage()->load('mod_myformular', $basePath);
```

Although not required, you might need to set the second $basePath if the needed language file is in the back-end.

For this instance however, Since you are not performing any CRUD operations and as is the getValue() method will always return the same value; it makes more sense to simply render the language translation text inside your default.php file.

Comment: My pleasure kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

Just a precision to complete this good answer : it works if your language file is in the default language folder (/yourSite/language/).

But if you want to load the language files of your custom module, you'll have to help Joomla like this :

```
JFactory::getLanguage()->load('mod_myformular', JPATH_SITE.'/modules/mod_myformular');
```